# How do I use a webscraper in python if I have a minimal OS?

Tags: python, web-scraping, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I am trying to make my raspberry pi interact with my wifi router using python. Since my router doesn't have an API, I need to use a webscraper or something similar in python to enter password, go to links, etc... I have tried using selenium and Beautifulsoup, but those both require web browsers that I cant get on raspbian minimal.

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver = webdriver.Firefox
```

and the result...

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'firefox'
```

Comment: How are you *interacting* with your router?

Comment: I need to be able to do things that I would be able to do in the admin Web interface

Answer (score 0):

Most routers use basic authentication. You can supply the username and password in the request URL by the following scheme: `https://USERNAME:PASSWORD@webaddress.com`

You don't need Selenium to make HTTP requests. Selenium is for browser automation. BeautifulSoup is for parsing HTML and has nothing to do with making HTTP requests.

You can use a library like `requests` to make HTTP requests without the need for any browser.

Comment: I tried this and it returned the HTML for the login page, in the javascript the password entered by the user is hashed multiple times before submitted, would this change anything? I am using a tp-link router by the way.

Comment: You can most likely still imitate the request. Look at what's being sent across the network, duplicate it. Make sure you're using the appropriate HTTP verb, headers, etc.